# first in app purchase transaction not working properly ios

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, storekit

i am trying to add in app purhase to my Unity3d-IOS project. I use Storekit. I add in app purchases to itunes account properly, also my code is ok (the same in app purchase logic & code work fine with my previous projects). However, currently, my in app purchase works well **except the first purchase transaction.**

In the first in app purchase either **system gives me the purchase before payment (before i click confirm)** or **transaction does not go proper SKPaymentTransactionState so that i send message to Unity and get my purchase** (i.e. even though i make payment and itunes gives me "successful purchase" dialog, it does not call proper purchase method).

Except the first in app purchase attempt, all in app purchases are successful and works well. As i said i've use same logic with my previous projects (which are totaly ok).

What might i can miss? Can anybody help?

*as you may guess, i use sandbox test accounts.

here is my code:

```
//
//  IAPController.m
//  Unity-iPhone
//
//  Created by dilara on 23/01/15.
//
//

#import "IAPController.h"

@interface IAPController ()

@end

@implementation IAPController

@synthesize productIdentifier;
@synthesize unityAppController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"in viewDidLoad!!!!!!!!!!");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(id)init
{
    self.iapViewController = unityAppController.rootViewController;

    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)requestProductwithProductID:(NSString *)productID //called by unity
{

    productIdentifier = productID;
    NSLog(@"in custom method (requestProductwithProductID), self.productIdentifier is %@ %s %@", productIdentifier, "param productID is ", productID);

    if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:productIdentifier]];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"no product found");
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"in productRequest of SKProductRequestDelegate");
    NSArray *products = response.products;

    if(products.count != 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"in if of productRequest method");
        self.product = products[0];
        productIdentifier = self.product.productIdentifier;
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:self.product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"in else of productRequest method, product not found");
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for(SKProduct *product in products)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product);
    }
}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSLog(@"in paymentQueueMethod of SKPaymentTransactionObserver");
    NSLog(@"initial count of transactions %d", transactions.count);


    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        NSLog(@"transaction is %@", transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
        NSLog(@"transaction id is %@", transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
        NSLog(@"original transaction id is %@", transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier);

        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"purchasing");
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                NSLog(@"purchased");
                UnitySendMessage("Panel_Store", "buyItem", [self.productIdentifier cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"restored");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"failed");
                if(transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
                {
                    NSLog(@"An error encountered %@", transaction.error.description);
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Cancel button is clicked! %@", transaction.error.description);
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
                NSLog(@"waiting for approval");
                break;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"count of transactions %d", transactions.count);
}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue removedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSLog(@"in removedTransactions method of SKPaymentTransactionObserver");
}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"in restoreCompletedTransactionFailedWithError method of SKPaymentTransactionObserver");
    NSLog(@"error in restoreCompletedTransactionFailedWithError is %@", error.description);
}

-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSLog(@"in paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished method of SKPaymentTransactionObserver");
}

-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"in requestDidFailWith method of SKRequestDelegate error is %@", error.description);
}

-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"in requestDidFinish method of SKRequestDelegate");
}

@end
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b8kdpy4lzhvuls5/IAPController.txt?dl=0

Comment: Now please include this in the question instead of in a comment. Also add the *actual* code in there, and not only a dropbox link.

Comment: thx for your consideration, i tried to paste my code here (not in comment) but i could not (there was some format problem), dropbox link is not requiring any download it directly opens file.

Comment: doesn't matter, eventually the link breaks, rendering the post here next to useless as a reference for others. try pasting the code again, select the code you pasted, then use the {} icon to format the code.